# jQuery how to queue fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I have two different events that call fadeIn / fadeOut on a div.  In some cases, the element could be the same.

```
<div class="details">Details</div>
<div class="details">Details2</div>

swiper.on('TouchStart', function () {
    $(".details:eq(" + swiper.previousIndex + ")").fadeOut({queue:true});
});
swiper.on('TouchEnd', function () {
    $(".details:eq(" + swiper.activeIndex + ")").fadeIn({queue: true});
});
```

I need the effect to wait if (and only if) the other is still running.

Comment: Sorry ive never used queue before, but what is it supposed to do, if not place the effects one after the other. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the syntax: `$(...).fadeIn({ queue: true });`

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vya1t0o/1/) that runs successsive `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` to a div.

Alternatively, if you are only doing 2 consecutive animations, you can run the second animation via the completion callback like this:

```
$(...).fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(); 
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7co9uory/3/) that runs `fadeOut`, and then `fadeIn` to a div.

**UPDATE**

This seems to work, which uses a queue for an in-memory jQuery object:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var option = { queue: 'tester', duration: 'slow' };
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        $({})
           .queue(function (next) {
               $('.test2').fadeOut('slow', next);
           })
           .queue(function (next) {
               $('.test1').fadeOut('slow', next);
           });  
     })
})
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vya1t0o/3/).

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

So you are triggering animations for the same element on two separate events and do not wish to overlap them. Then you can always use jQuery's [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to cancel the immediately running animation on the element, before you do anything. For example: `$(...).stop().fadeIn()`. You can also tell `stop()` to clear any queued animation for that element, if you want to.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vya1t0o/7/) that uses the `stop()`. Watch the blue div as you hover in or out of the first div. If you do it quickly, the previous animation is stopped right away.

Comment: The first option is what I want but doesn't work with different elements (at least isn't working for me).  The second callback is irrelevant as the triggering events are what need to initiate the effect.

Comment: For subsequently animating another element, best to use the callback. What do you mean why *as the triggering events are what need to initiate the event*? If you have subsequent animations, the event can only trigger the first, and the first can trigger the second. No reason why you can't pass selectors from the event to the first function and to the next.

Comment: TouchStart and TouchEnd events need  to fire the effect.  They don't happen a predetermined amount of time apart.  In short, it depends on the user's action.  I just don't want them stepping on top of each other if TouchEnd is fired before TouchStart ends.  This seems to be exactly what queues are for.

Comment: About your comment *I just don't want them stepping on top of each other if TouchEnd is fired before TouchStart ends*, you can always tell jQuery to `stop()` the next queued animation for an element before doing anything on your TouchEnd (e.g. `$(..).stop().fadeOut()`). The `stop()` method also accept a parameter if you want to clear any other queued animation for the element.

Comment: @drewschmaltz, let me know if my 2nd update helps. I can't test `TouchStart` so I used mouse events.